# Windows 10 Anaconda Graphviz Error Not working

Tags: python, anaconda, graphviz

Everything runs fine until the line "graph.render("iris")". Then I get this error: ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'iris'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

```
graph.render("iris")
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-13-c002c0ff127c>", line 1, in <module>
graph.render("iris")

File "C:\Users\Rafay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py", line 
175, in render
rendered = backend.render(self._engine, self._format, filepath)

File "C:\Users\Rafay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend.py", line 
127, in render
raise ExecutableNotFound(args)

ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'iris'], make 
sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

I have Windows 10 and am using Anaconda and spyder. Complete code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import graphviz
from util import visualize_iris


# load iris petal data set
iris = load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target



# create Decision Tree Classifier object
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()

# fit Decision Tree to Data
dt = dt.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

# look at the importance of each feature
print(dt.feature_importances_)
print(dt.score(X, y))

# visualize decision tree
# tree visualization
dot_data = export_graphviz(dt, out_file=None,
                                feature_names=iris.feature_names,
                                class_names=iris.target_names,
                                filled=True, rounded=True,
                                special_characters=True
                                )

graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
graph.render("iris")
```

Again,everything runs fine until the line "graph.render("iris")". Then I get this error above.

Thank you so much everyone, you all are awesome!

Comment: So, are the Graphviz executables (`dot` and friends) installed on your system, or not? You can download an installer from https://www.graphviz.org/download/.

Comment: I downloaded the 2.38 Stable Release .zip file and have no idea what to do with it. there are several files available for windows.

Comment: I used the following in anaconda prompt: conda install python-graphviz I no longer get an error. I only see this in iPython console though: Out[4]: 'iris.pdf' I am not seeing any output

Answer (score 6):

Please note that I am using windows 10. some of the following may or may not applicable for other versions of windows or operating systems:

** Note 2: ** 
 
"the Graphviz bin file address on your system" can be **C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin** or any other path you installed Graphviz there.
We have problem not only with Graphviz but also with other external EXE files we want to use in Jupyter.
The reason is when jupyter wants to import a package it looks in working directory to find it and when it fails to find the package it returns such errors.
What we can do is tackle this is as follows:
1) check if the Graphviz is installed on your system and if not you can download and install it from:

https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html 

and then install it. When you installing Graphviz, keep in mind where (in which folder) you are installing it.
If you see the above error when you use

```
import graphviz
```

then you have several options:

2) you can call the .exe file in the ipynb via

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r'the Graphviz bin file address on your system'
```

It is my experience that it is only works for the same ipynb that I am working with and every time that I open the notebook I need to call this lines of code.

3) If you want the Jupyter where to find the exe file, you need to set environmenal path.
In windows 10 you can do this going to:
Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > Path > Edit > New 
 
and then add the "the Graphviz bin file address on your system"
In windows 8 or lower go to :
Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables 
and then add the ;(semicolon) + "the Graphviz bin file address on your system" to the end of path string
Note: remember to restart your machine.

4) and even this does not work, define a variable going to:
Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables and then:

[image: Start to define an environmental variable]

Then define a variable as this:
[image: Remember to name the variable Graphviz]

Remember to name the variable Graphviz. At last restart your PC and hope it works.

Comment: +1 import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r'the Graphviz bin file address on your system' fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

As the Python `graphviz` [module documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) says,

> To render the generated DOT source code, you also need to install
>   Graphviz ([download page](https://www.graphviz.org/download/)).
>
> Make sure that the directory containing the dot executable is on your
>   systems’ path.

Comment: Hello guys,

Thanks for your help. There are multiple downloads for Windows on that page, which one should I pick? Sorry as I said this is my first time, I am a beginner. And how do I "Make sure that the directory containing the dot executable is on your systems’ path"? Again, I am using Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: I downloaded the 2.38 Stable Release .zip file and have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: I used the following in anaconda prompt: conda install python-graphviz

I no longer get an error. I only see this in iPython console though: Out[4]: 'iris.pdf'

I am not seeing any output

Comment: The output is the file `iris.pdf` which has been created somewhere, most likely in your Python program's current working directory (`os.getcwd()`)